# Layouts not scaling properly

Tags: java, android

I have 7 image buttons I am displaying and while editing the xml the preview looks perfect, however when I launch the app in an emulator it doesn't seem to scale and is cutting off the images.

It should look like this:

```
-0-0-
0-0-0
-0-0-
```

Where the '0's are the buttons. I have it setup for one overall relative layout and three linear layouts. The middle places first then the top and bottom align off the middle.

Here is my XML file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:id="@+id/activity_color_wheel">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/middle_left">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/dode1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/dodecagon1"
        android:onClick="selected"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/dode2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/dodecagon2"
        android:onClick="selected"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/dode3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/dodecagon3"
        android:onClick="selected"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/middle_left"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/bottom">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/dode4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/dodecagon4"
        android:onClick="selected"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/dode5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/dodecagon5"
        android:onClick="selected"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/middle_left"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/top">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/dode6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/dodecagon6"
        android:onClick="selected"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/dode7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/dodecagon7"
        android:onClick="selected"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
</LinearLayout>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="25dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Basically the top and bottom layouts get cut off near the bottom. I figure i'm missing some kind of scaling property, but i'm not sure.

Comment: If the answer helped you please mark it as the solution. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All of your views' width and height are "wrap content".
In that case if the total images width/height is greater then the screen's width/height it will just cut off.
what you should do is:
1) set the LinearLayouts width to "match parent".
2) set weight to the children views as you wish.
3) set children width to 0dp for better performance.

Example code snippet:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/middle_left">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/dode1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/testImage"
        android:onClick="selected"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/dode2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/testImage"
        android:onClick="selected"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/dode3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/testImage"
        android:onClick="selected"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Good luck.

Comment: So if it's cutting off at the top/bottoms wouldn't that be height and not width? Would I need to switch the height and width ?

Comment: No. when you set weight and width to 0 you are basically telling the layout you want to let the weight distribution set the width for you. That is true for a **LinearLayout**. So if you want to set the heights of the images to NOT cut of as well you should do the same thing **if the parent containing is a linear layout**. In your case, regarding the height issue your parent layout is **RelativeLayout**. So what you should do is just set relative attributes such as ** layout_below** to reference between all layout, as well as set reference to a parent view, such as **layout_alignParentTop**.

Comment: and its possible to have 3 separate linear layouts and have two reference another one?

Comment: of course, as long as they are all direct children of the same parent relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is only with the top and bottom images, then you only need to add a `ScrollView` as a parent to your `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: This will add a Scrolling option to your views if their height exceed the screen height.

Comment: Ideally I'd like it to scale for every screen and not have to scroll to use it

Comment: Then you should use weights and add adjustViewBounds="true" to your image butons